# URL throwing failed to open stream and header already sent error

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, apache, .htaccess

All my requests are re-written to index.php. See my .htaccess file below.

```
IndexIgnore *

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    #Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# BEGIN EXPIRES
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
    ExpiresActive On
    ExpiresDefault "access plus 10 days"
    ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
    ExpiresByType image/jpg  "access plus 1 month"

    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header append Cache-Control "public"
      </IfModule>
</IfModule>
# END EXPIRES

<FilesMatch “.(ttf|otf|eot|woff)$”>
    <IfModule mod_headers.c>
        Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin “*”
    </IfModule>
</FilesMatch>
```

I exited at line 2 of my index.php for the sake of debugging. See my index.php below

```
<?php
exit('here');
session_start();
error_reporting(-1);
    .
    .
    .
```

When I use this URL -

http://www.example.com/admincp/site/editor/layout?csrf_token=852f2d49ab5d27fd061a164a5e059531&val[page]=feed&val[column]=2&middle[2.23334858434E+12][widget]=content&middle[2.23334858434E+12][settings]=&right[c7ef099029aca9f5d297d79757ea100c][widget]=plugin::ads|ads&right[c7ef099029aca9f5d297d79757ea100c][settings]=&right[eed08f19fa0e3fb7d017e5b32d9eba16][widget]=plugin::blog|latest&right[eed08f19fa0e3fb7d017e5b32d9eba16][settings]=&right[67a8d113cceb768272adedb97e5e349c][widget]=plugin::music|latest&right[67a8d113cceb768272adedb97e5e349c][settings]=&right[31dc5ba68111024770ae8d2f6c12312d][widget]=plugin::page|latest&right[31dc5ba68111024770ae8d2f6c12312d][settings]=&right[d66d56bf471a39e6e2b4ac58b4733304][widget]=plugin::video|latest&right[d66d56bf471a39e6e2b4ac58b4733304][settings]=

Everything works fine i.e 'here' is displayed in the browser

But when I use this URL -

http://www.example.com/admincp/site/editor/layout?csrf_token=852f2d49ab5d27fd061a164a5e059531&val%5Bpage%5D=feed&val%5Bcolumn%5D=2&middle%5B2.23334858434E%2B12%5D%5Bwidget%5D=content&middle%5B2.23334858434E%2B12%5D%5Bsettings%5D=&right%5Bc7ef099029aca9f5d297d79757ea100c%5D%5Bwidget%5D=plugin%3A%3Aads%7Cads&right%5Bc7ef099029aca9f5d297d79757ea100c%5D%5Bsettings%5D=&right%5Beed08f19fa0e3fb7d017e5b32d9eba16%5D%5Bwidget%5D=plugin%3A%3Ablog%7Clatest&right%5Beed08f19fa0e3fb7d017e5b32d9eba16%5D%5Bsettings%5D=&right%5B67a8d113cceb768272adedb97e5e349c%5D%5Bwidget%5D=plugin%3A%3Amusic%7Clatest&right%5B67a8d113cceb768272adedb97e5e349c%5D%5Bsettings%5D=&right%5B31dc5ba68111024770ae8d2f6c12312d%5D%5Bwidget%5D=plugin%3A%3Apage%7Clatest&right%5B31dc5ba68111024770ae8d2f6c12312d%5D%5Bsettings%5D=&right%5Bd66d56bf471a39e6e2b4ac58b4733304%5D%5Bwidget%5D=plugin%3A%3Avideo%7Clatest&right%5Bd66d56bf471a39e6e2b4ac58b4733304%5D%5Bsettings%5D=

I get the following errors.

> Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in
>   Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent in
>   Unknown on line 0

Note that this only happens on a specific server. The two URLs works and behave the same way on other servers and localhost.The difference between the two URLs is just url encoding.

I cannot use the first URL because jQuery automatically encodes my request body when I use the form.AjaxSubmit() function.

Answer (score 0):

> mod_rewrite has to unescape URLs before mapping them, so
>   backreferences are unescaped at the time they are applied. Using the B
>   flag, non-alphanumeric characters in backreferences will be escaped

So try with the B flag

```
RewriteRule ^ index.php [B,L]
```

[RewriteRule Flags](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html)

Other possible explanation and solutions can be found here: http://dracos.co.uk/code/apache-rewrite-problem/

Comment: The issue was not resolved after modifying the flag and restarting Apache. Thanks anyway.